# InflateException in Google Cardboard tutorial

Tags: android, google-cardboard

I'm a trying to render a Google Cardboard app rendering droidar objects, but for now i'm trying to display a simple cardboardview using the official tutorial (https://developers.google.com/cardboard/android/get-started) but I have an exception :

```
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #21: Error inflating class com.google.vrtoolkit.cardboard.CardboardView
```

And i can't find a solution, it's starting to drive me crazy...
Could you help me, please? Here's my code :

My Manifest.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="lp.s3im.cardboarddemo"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="15"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <category android:name="com.google.intent.category.CARDBOARD" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

MainActivity :

```
package lp.s3im.cardboarddemo;

import java.nio.FloatBuffer;

import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig;

import com.google.vrtoolkit.cardboard.CardboardActivity;

import com.google.vrtoolkit.cardboard.CardboardView;
import com.google.vrtoolkit.cardboard.Eye;
import com.google.vrtoolkit.cardboard.HeadTransform;
import com.google.vrtoolkit.cardboard.Viewport;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Vibrator;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends CardboardActivity implements
    CardboardView.StereoRenderer {

private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
private static final float Z_NEAR = 0.1f;
private static final float Z_FAR = 100.0f;
private static final float CAMERA_Z = 0.01f;
private static final float TIME_DELTA = 0.3f;
private static final float YAW_LIMIT = 0.12f;
private static final float PITCH_LIMIT = 0.12f;
private static final int COORDS_PER_VERTEX = 3;
// We keep the light always position just above the user.
private static final float[] LIGHT_POS_IN_WORLD_SPACE = new float[] { 0.0f,
        2.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };
private final float[] lightPosInEyeSpace = new float[4];
private FloatBuffer floorVertices;
private FloatBuffer floorColors;
private FloatBuffer floorNormals;
private FloatBuffer cubeVertices;
private FloatBuffer cubeColors;
private FloatBuffer cubeFoundColors;
private FloatBuffer cubeNormals;
private int cubeProgram;
private int floorProgram;
private int cubePositionParam;
private int cubeNormalParam;
private int cubeColorParam;
private int cubeModelParam;
private int cubeModelViewParam;
private int cubeModelViewProjectionParam;
private int cubeLightPosParam;
private int floorPositionParam;
private int floorNormalParam;
private int floorColorParam;
private int floorModelParam;
private int floorModelViewParam;
private int floorModelViewProjectionParam;
private int floorLightPosParam;
private float[] modelCube;
private float[] camera;
private float[] view;
private float[] headView;
private float[] modelViewProjection;
private float[] modelView;
private float[] modelFloor;
private int score = 0;
private float objectDistance = 12f;
private float floorDepth = 20f;
private Vibrator vibrator;

// private CardboardOverlayView overlayView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    CardboardView cardboardView = (CardboardView) findViewById(R.id.cardboard_view);
    // Associate a CardboardView.StereoRenderer with cardboardView.
    cardboardView.setRenderer(this);
    // Associate the cardboardView with this activity.
    setCardboardView(cardboardView);

    // Initialize other objects here.
    modelCube = new float[16];
    camera = new float[16];
    view = new float[16];
    modelViewProjection = new float[16];
    modelView = new float[16];
    modelFloor = new float[16];
    headView = new float[16];
    vibrator = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onDrawEye(Eye arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onFinishFrame(Viewport arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onNewFrame(HeadTransform arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    arg0.getHeadView(headView, 0);

}

@Override
public void onRendererShutdown() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onSurfaceChanged(int arg0, int arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onSurfaceCreated(EGLConfig arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="lp.s3im.cardboarddemo.MainActivity" >

<com.google.vrtoolkit.cardboard.CardboardView
    android:id="@+id/cardboard_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

Edit : With the following code i can display the camera with the starpreview method, but i can't use the preview of the andAR library (https://code.google.com/p/andar/), which does a black screen. I don"t understand if it is because it's overloaded or not.

```
package edu.dhbw.andar.sample;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import edu.dhbw.andar.ARToolkit;
import edu.dhbw.andar.AndARActivity;
import edu.dhbw.andar.exceptions.AndARException;

/**
* Example of an application that makes use of the AndAR toolkit.
*
* @author Tobi
*
*/
public class CustomActivity extends AndARActivity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    CustomObject someObject;
    ARToolkit artoolkit;
    SurfaceView surfaceView;
    SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
    Camera camera;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
            CustomRenderer renderer = new CustomRenderer();// optional, may be set
                                                                                                            // to null
            super.setNonARRenderer(renderer);// or might be omited
            try {
                    // register a object for each marker type
                    artoolkit = super.getArtoolkit();
                    someObject = new CustomObject("test", "patt.hiro", 80.0,
                                    new double[] { 0, 0 });
                    artoolkit.registerARObject(someObject);
                    someObject = new CustomObject("test", "android.patt", 80.0,
                                    new double[] { 0, 0 });
                    artoolkit.registerARObject(someObject);
                    someObject = new CustomObject("test", "barcode.patt", 80.0,
                                    new double[] { 0, 0 });
                    artoolkit.registerARObject(someObject);
            } catch (AndARException ex) {
                    // handle the exception, that means: show the user what happened
                    System.out.println("");
            }
            surfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceView);
            surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
            surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
            surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
                    int height) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            startCamera(holder, width, height);

    }

    @Override
    public SurfaceView getSurfaceView() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return super.getSurfaceView();
    }

    @Override
    public void startPreview() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.startPreview();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.surfaceDestroyed(holder);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            camera = Camera.open();
    try {
        camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
    }

    /**
     * Inform the user about exceptions that occurred in background threads.
     * This exception is rather severe and can not be recovered from. TODO
     * Inform the user and shut down the application.
     */
    @Override
    public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable ex) {
            Log.e("AndAR EXCEPTION", ex.getMessage());
            finish();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            // getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();
            switch (id) {
            // case R.id.settings:
            // break;
            default:
                    break;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void startCamera(SurfaceHolder sh, int width, int height) {
            Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();  
               List<Camera.Size> sizes = parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();  
               Camera.Size cs = sizes.get(0);  
               parameters.setPreviewSize(cs.width, cs.height);  
               camera.setParameters(parameters);

        try {
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(sh);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

        camera.startPreview();
    }

    private void stopCamera() {
            //camera.removeCallback(this);

            camera.stopPreview();
        camera.release();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Include the libprotobuf-java-2.3-nano.jar file in your build path.

Comment: Thank you, now i can launch the application, but i have a black view (probably an virtual environnement), but i want to get what my camera see and show it in the cardboardview and then display droidar objects in it.